# php - some data lost when posted to server

Tags: php, apache

I have a page which will post a large array (nearly 1000 integers) to the server.

And everything goes well on my own computer.

But when I deploy my code to cloud server, strange things happen.

for the same request, in my case, is(POST, here put args to url for convinience):

`getPersonInfo.php?IDList[]=1&IDList[]=2&.....`

when I echo the length of IDList by `echo count($_POST['IDList'])`, the local server(WAMP) print `1102`, but the cloud server(LAMP) print `1001`, 101 elements lost!

I've carefully compared the tow request, they are entirely same.

So it must be the LAMP server dropped some data posted from browser.

I've also looked up `post_max_size` in `php.ini`, it is `500M`. seems no problem.

So why the data would lost?

By the way, the web site goes well on could just yesterday. Today I tried to remove python by `apt remove python`. Is this matters?